# Unexpected string in JS with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, string

I write small page and in this code I have  error. I want to use this way because Isotope doesn't read the width and height from styles in HTML tags.

```
var winw = $(window).width();
var plmt_w = winw / 10;
var plmt_h = plmt_w;

var css = '.plmt { width:' plmt_w '; height:' plmt_h ';}',
.....
```

Comment: I'm unclear as to what you are asking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ajm and Amit Joki said, you need + operators to concatenate strings.

But, since `$(window).width()` returns an unitless value, you need to add 'px' for it to be a valid css string:

```
var css = '.plmt { width:' + plmt_w + 'px; height:' + plmt_h + 'px;}',
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `+` operator to join the strings:

```
var css = '.plmt { width:' + plmt_w + '; height:' + plmt_h + ';}';
```

Comment: @DamianNowakowski glad to have helped you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `+` operator to concatenate strings:

```
var css = '.plmt { width:' + plmt_w + '; height:' + plmt_h + ';}',
```